# Change title of payment method programmatically

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods, title

I need to **change the title** of my custom payment gateway programmaticaly based on some **conditions**. 
How to do it I could not figure out? I tried to capture **`paymentfilter_payment_method_is_active`** event but that event did not have anything related to title.